# CONFUSION MATRIX, R,

Tags: r, loops, confusion-matrix

I need little help with the following code below. I have to setup a loop to train a neural network model on the TRAINING data with a different number of epochs each time by starting from 5 and adding 3 until I reach 20. Then I have to calculate a line chart showing the accuracy with differing numbers of epochs. I also have to keep all the parameters same as shown. Much of the code is what was given by our instructor. I added the `epochs= c(5,8,11,14,17,20)` to create a list of epochs and the `error.rate = vector()` where I intend to store the accuracy from each loop into a vector. The accuracy I want is from the confusion matrix and is found from the formula

`h2o.hit_ratio_table(<model>,train = TRUE)[1,2]`

The problem I face is that I have tried to create a loop. I am trying to get the results from each loop. I have labled the first part of the loop as X to try to put it into the vector for the accuracy for each loop into a vector `error.rate=h2o.hit_ratio_table(x,train=TRUE)[1,2])`.

However, it gives an error.

```
> Error in is(object, "H2OModelMetrics") : object 'X' not found In
> addition: Warning messages: 1: In 1:epochs : numerical expression has
> 6 elements: only the first used
```

Moreover, when I remove the `error.rate=......` part, the function runs fine but there is no way to find the values of the accuracy.

I am a noob at R so a little help will be much appreciated.

```
s <- proc.time()
 epochs= c(5,8,11,14,17,20)
 error.rate = vector()

 for (epoch in 1:epochs){#set up loop to go around 6 times
 X=h2o.deeplearning(x = 2:785,  # column numbers for predictors
               y = 1,   # column number for label
               training_frame = train_h2o, # data in H2O format
               activation = "RectifierWithDropout", # mathematical   activation function
               input_dropout_ratio = 0.2, # % of inputs dropout, because some inputs might not matter.
               hidden_dropout_ratios = c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25), # % for nodes dropout, because maybe we don't need full connections. Improves generalisability
               balance_classes = T, # over/under samples so that all classes are similar size.
               hidden = c(50,50,50,50), # two layers of 100 nodes
               momentum_stable = 0.99,
               nesterov_accelerated_gradient = T,
               error.rate=h2o.hit_ratio_table(x,train=TRUE)[1,2])
proc.time() - s}
```

Comment: You are doing 'for(epoch in 1:epochs)'. Here the 'epoch' term changes each loop (and usually you use it within the loop but i don't see it?). '1:epochs' will not work as you think it should. It is taking the first element of epochs (5) and basically saying 'for(epoch in 1:5)' where epoch is 1, then 2, ... and then 5. You want something like 'for(epoch in epochs)' and if you DO want a sequence from 1:each epoch in your code you should write it within the loop. Also, 'x' and your error.rate result is rewritten each time it loops. You should run 'error.rate[epoch] =' instead.

Comment: Thanks Evan, This is very useful....that's why I couldn't get the loop to run

Comment: Allow me to copy this into an answer so you can mark this thread completed then. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Evan, you have been really helpful!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `for(epoch in 1:epochs)`. Here the 'epoch' term changes each loop (and usually you use it within the loop but i don't see it?). `1:epochs` will not work as you think it should. It is taking the first element of epochs (5) and basically saying `for(epoch in 1:5)` where epoch is 1, then 2, ... and then 5. You want something like `for(epoch in epochs)` and if you DO want a sequence from 1:each epoch in your code you should write it within the loop.

Also, `x` is rewritten each time it loops. You should initialize it and save subsets of it each loop instead:

```
epochs= c(5,8,11,14,17,20)
 x <- list() # save as list #option 1
 y <- list() # for an option 2
 for (epoch in epochs){ #set up loop to go around 6 times
   X[[epoch]] = h2o.deeplearning(... )
   # or NOW you can somehow use 1:epoch where each loop epoch changes
 }
```

But I would really focus on there is no use of using your epoch in your for loop as I see in your post. Perhaps find out where you want to use it...